# Revisiting the UK after being deported

Tags: uk, eu-citizens, deportation

I was deported from the Uk 7 years ago. My final release date is expired and as a EU citizen, can I visit the UK without any special permission or a security clearance? I was told never to return until my final release date fully expired.

Comment: For what reason were you deported?

Comment: "Final release date"? What does this mean? Were you in prison in the UK?

Comment: EU nationals can be refused entry to the UK in some circumstances https://hub.unlock.org.uk/knowledgebase/eu-nationals-coming-and-staying-in-the-uk/

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.